# How can I rotate and move an object to another object position and rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

First some screenshots.

The first is the object I want to move to and to rotate to it's rotation :
This is the target: You can see it's position and rotation :

[image: Target]

This screenshot is of the object I want to rotate and move so it will be positioned at the same position and rotation like the target :

[image: Object to rotate and move to the target position and rotation]

They look like the same rotation and position but the object I want to rotate and move have Animator and when the game start I play animation that rotate and move the object when the animation ending playing I want to rotate an move it to be like the target position and rotation.

This script is attached to the object I want to rotate and move :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The target marker.
    public Transform target;
    // Angular speed in radians per sec.
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    private Animator anim;
    private bool started = true;
    private float animationLenth;
    private bool ended = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Whilefun.FPEKit.FPESaveLoadManager.gameStarted == true && started == true)
        {
            Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.Instance.BeginCutscene();
            anim.enabled = true;
            anim.Play("Stand Up", 0, 0);
            animationLenth = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
            StartCoroutine(AnimationEnded());
            started = false;
        }

        if (ended == true)
        {
            // Determine which direction to rotate towards
            Vector3 targetDirection = transform.position - target.position;

            // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
            float singleStep = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
            Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

            // Calculate a rotation a step closer to the target and applies rotation to this object
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AnimationEnded()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animationLenth);

        ended = true;
        Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.Instance.EndCutscene();
        anim.enabled = false;
        //transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I'm using the ended flag to tell when the animation ended play and then start to rotate(I need also to make a movement) in the Update. But it's not rotting too smooth and not moving yet.

I want it to rotate and move smooth like transition from when the animation clip ended until it will be the same position and rotation like the target.

But in the end now only rotating in the end it's like this and not like the target :

[image: Not same as target rotation and not moving yet]

I'm using RotateTowards and MoveTowards :

```
if (ended == true)
        {
            // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
            var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Rotate our transform a step closer to the target's.
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, target.rotation, step);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
            headTransform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(headTransform.rotation, target.rotation, step);
        }
```

This is working fine. But it's in the Update (Removed the Rigidbody so it's fine to be in the Update and not FixedUpdate). How can I make this to work inside the IEnumerator after the WaitForSeconds when the Coroutine has finished ?

This is how I'm doing it now inside the IEnumerator :

The problem is that it's never ending the while it keep looping inside the while.
It's not freezing the editor or something but it's never finish the while loop.

```
IEnumerator AnimationEnded()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animationLenth);

        Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
        while (Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, target.position) > 0.1f)
        {
            var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Rotate our transform a step closer to the target's.
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, target.rotation, step);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
            headTransform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(headTransform.rotation, target.rotation, step);

            yield return null;
        }

        Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.Instance.EndCutscene();
        anim.enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have to use `Update`? Can't you simply continue using the Coroutine instead of letting `Update` poll-check a bool flag?

Comment: Did you try [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)? Also note: If this thing you are moving/rotating is a `Rigidbody` you shouldn't do it by using `Transform` in `Update` but rather `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` in `FixedUpdate`

Comment: Also you are telling it to RotateTowards in order to **look at** the target object ... you do not tell it to copy the targets rotation....

Comment: @derHugo How do I make it in the continue ? When the continue ended do I need to use while loop for the rotating and moving ?

Comment: Yes for example .. but don't forget to `yield return null;` within it

Comment: @derHugo I updated my question with what I'm doing inside the IEnumerator :

The problem is that it's never ending the while it keep looping inside the while.
It's not freezing the editor or something but it's never finish the while loop. And I'm not sure if the condition > 0.1 is right logic and not something to check for the accurate exactly position/rotation or both and how to do it ?

Comment: You never change the value of `currentPosition` within the loop so the distance never changes ... what you rather want is `while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position)){ ...}` also yes you should add a condition for both, the rotation and the position. Actually you could do something like `while(transform.position != target.position || transform.rotation != target.rotation || headTransform.rotation != target.rotation){ ...}`